# Django - Parsing SQL Querys to QuerySet

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm a beginner with Django and Python but I need some help to parse my sql query to Django query set. I have a database which contains a table called "Temperatura".

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Temperatura(models.Model):

    data = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, unique=True)
    maxima = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    minima = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    estacao = models.CharField(max_length=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self)
```

I'd like to make this sql query:

```
select estacao,
       (avg(maxima) + avg(minima))/2 as TempMedia,
       max(maxima) as maxima,
       min(minima) as minima
from Temperatura 
group by estacao
```

Comment: Learn how to use django ORM [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/).

Answer (score 0):

Django allows you to perform [raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries)